# fields and field values are not pushed into influxdb 2.0 bucket

Tags: python, pandas, influxdb-2, influxdb-python

Here a dataframe for stock XYZ:

```
                               timestamp   open   high   low    close   volume
timestamp                                                                     
2021-02-04 04:21:00  2021-02-04 04:21:00   1.41   1.41  1.41   1.4100    100.0
2021-02-04 04:22:00  2021-02-04 04:22:00   1.41   1.41  1.41   1.4100   1100.0
2021-02-04 04:23:00  2021-02-04 04:23:00   1.41   1.41  1.40   1.4000    200.0
2021-02-04 04:27:00  2021-02-04 04:27:00   1.40   1.40  1.40   1.4000   1010.0
2021-02-04 04:28:00  2021-02-04 04:28:00   1.40   1.40  1.40   1.4000   2000.0
...                                  ...    ...    ...   ...      ...      ...
2021-02-04 19:55:00  2021-02-04 19:55:00   9.85   9.90  9.77   9.7700   9799.0
2021-02-04 19:56:00  2021-02-04 19:56:00   9.76   9.93  9.76   9.8501  24665.0
2021-02-04 19:57:00  2021-02-04 19:57:00   9.95   9.97  9.91   9.9200   7544.0
2021-02-04 19:58:00  2021-02-04 19:58:00   9.97  10.09  9.94   9.9500  21250.0
2021-02-04 19:59:00  2021-02-04 19:59:00  10.06  10.09  9.95  10.0900  26640.0
```

I am trying to write this dataframe into influxdb2 bucket using this function:

```
def get_stock_data(symbol):
    points = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        point = Point(measurement_name="XYZ").time(pd.Timestamp(df.index[i]).isoformat())
        point.field("open", df["open"][i])
        point.field("high", df["high"][i])
        point.field("low", df["low"][i])
        point.field("close", df["close"][i])
        point.field("volume", df["volume"][i])
        point.tag("my_tag", "my_tag_value")
        points.append(point)
    return points
```

I know it is working partially because I can see the measurement XYZ, but I can't  see the fields and field values in the influxdb ui or Grafana. I tried many thing as modifying the timestamp, reinstalling influxdb2, etc. Why the fields and field values are not pushed into the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_stock_data(symbol):
    points = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        time_fetch=str(pd.Timestamp(df.index[i]).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))
        point = Point(measurement_name=symbol).time(time_fetch)
        point.field("open", df["open"][i])
        point.field("high", df["high"][i])
        point.field("low", df["low"][i])
        point.field("close", df["close"][i])
        point.field("volume", df["volume"][i])
        points.append(point)
    return points
```

Using `.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')` seems to fix my error.